# Find a SVD of $A=u_1v_1^\intercal +2u_2v_2^\intercal +3u_3v_3^\intercal$

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, svd, orthonormal

Find a SVD of $A=u_1v_1^\intercal +2u_2v_2^\intercal +3u_3v_3^\intercal$ where $\{u_1,u_2,u_3\}\subset\mathbb R^M$ and $\{v_1,v_2,v_3\}\subset\mathbb R^N$ are orthonormal sets.

The SVD is $A=U\Sigma T^\intercal$, so I begin by finding $AA^\intercal=u_1u_1^\intercal+4u_2u_2^\intercal+9u_3u_3^\intercal\in\mathbb R^{M\times M}$. I now need to find the eigenvalues and eigenvectors, what could they be?

$(u_1u_1^\intercal+4u_2u_2^\intercal+9u_3u_3^\intercal)v=\lambda v\implies (u_1^\intercal v)u_1+4(u_2^\intercal v)u_2+9(u_3^\intercal v)u_3=\lambda v\implies...what?$

Likewise, $AA^\intercal=v_1v_1^\intercal+2v_2v_2^\intercal+3v_3v_3^\intercal\in\mathbb R^{N\times N}$, and what are the eigenvalues? Just need the eigenvalues for this one.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: There's another way to look at this, which is to express that SVD of $A$ as $A = \sum_{i=1}^n \sigma_i u_i v_i^T$. (This formula is useful because it shows how to find a low rank approximation to $A$.)

Comment: You already have the singular value decomposition (and the eigenvalues if you so wished), you just have to get used to switching between the vector and matrix (in that basis) representations

Comment: This is what I was looking for! Actually, I wasn't but this is great-thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you already computed $AA^T=u_1u_1^T+4u_2u_2^T+9u_3u_3^T$, let us write its *matrix representation* $[AA^T]_\beta$ with respect to orthonormal basis $\beta=\{u_1,u_2,u_3\}$. The first column is $[AA^Tu_1]_\beta = [(u_1u_1^T+4u_2u_2^T+9u_3u_3^T)u_1]_\beta = [u_1]_\beta=\begin{pmatrix}
    1 \\
    0\\
    0
   \end{pmatrix}$; the second column is $[AA^Tu_2]_\beta = [4u_2]_\beta=\begin{pmatrix}
    0 \\
    4\\
    0
   \end{pmatrix}$; and the third column is $[AA^Tu_3]_\beta = [9u_3]_\beta=\begin{pmatrix}
    0 \\
    0\\
    9
   \end{pmatrix}$. This gives $[AA^T]_\beta=\begin{pmatrix}
    1 & 0 & 0 \\
    0 & 4 & 0\\
    0& 0 &9
   \end{pmatrix}$, which I think you can see what its eigenvalues are.

Also, from here, can you see what the eigenvectors of $AA^T$ are? Now make a guess of what the eigenvalues and eigenvectors are for an expression like $a_1 u_1 u_1^T + a_2 u_2 u_2^T +\cdots + a_n u_n u_n^T$ where $\{u_1,\ldots,u_n\}$ forms an orthonormal basis.

Comment: Maybe I'll understand this some day

Comment: why is the first column $AA^Tu_1$? and what is $[AA^T]_\beta$? (I mean I know it's in a different basis, but what does it mean)

Comment: @Stacker Those are the columns of the matrix $[AA^T]_\beta$, not of $AA^T$. It is a change of coordinates. What is nice is that once you change the coordinate representation, the eigenvalues stay the same.

Comment: @Stacker In general, if you have a $n\times n$ square matrix $M$, and $\beta = \{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$ is a basis, then the matrix representation of $M$ with respect to $\beta$ is this new matrix $[M]_\beta$, where $[M]_\beta = [[Mv_1]_\beta \, [Mv_2]_\beta  \cdots [Mv_n]_\beta]$. Note $[x]_\beta$ is the coordinate vector of $x$ with respect to $\beta$. If $x = \sum c_i v_i$, then the coordinate vector of $x$ with respect to $\beta$ is $[x]_\beta = \begin{pmatrix}c_1\\ \vdots \\c_n\end{pmatrix}$.

Comment: @Stacker Let say you have an $n\times n$ matrix $M$. Then you can think of it as a linear transformation on $\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^n$. Now in $\mathbb R^n$, it is typical to think of the standard basis as the axes, but this may not be the most convenient to understand the map $M$ . If $\beta = \{v_1,\ldots,v_n\}$ is a basis, then the matrix representation $[M]_\beta$ is the same transformation as $M$ except we are taking $v_1,\ldots,v_n$ as our new axes (a change of coordinates).

Comment: @Stacker  For example, our $AA^T$ here. It is not clear what exactly $AA^T$ is doing. However, once we write in with respect to $\beta = \{u_1,u_2,u_3\}$, we get a diagonal matrix. What does that mean and why is that desirable? Now it is easy to understand what this diagonal matrix does: It stretches each axis by the scalar amount on the diagonal. So if we see $[AA^T]_\beta = diag(1,4,9)$, this means $AA^T$ stretches in the $u_1$ direction by a factor of 1; the $u_2$ direction by a factor of 4; and in the $u_3$ direction by a factor of 9. Note this is precisely what eigenvector/eigenvalue mean

Comment: Wait, we only got lucky here because the basis happened to give us a diagonal matrix. Because it's probably not diagonal in the standard basis or other basis. Thanks for the comments and answer! I learned about bases 5 years ago and this is a nice recap :) back to my homework now.